# How do I update a table from a flat file in SSIS, but not update fields if the source is blank?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that runs daily to flush and fill a table that contains a list of sites, using a flat file source that is sent from a client. The package does this over the following steps:

1. Truncates the site staging table
2. Loads the contents of the flat file into the staging table
3. Truncates the dim table
4. Loads the contents of the staging table into the dim table

The file contains fields for the opening/closing hours of each site, however sometimes these fields are blank (text fields with a value of `''`, they aren't `null`).

I am trying to find a way to modify step 2 (or 4) above to still update the table from source, but to not update the opening/closing hours fields if the source has a value of `''`.

Comment: Put a [conditional split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/conditional-split-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) in your data flow task (I assume this is what step 2 is) to redirect rows where opening/closing hour is blank. Then just do nothing with this branch, so only relevant rows are loaded to your staging table.

Comment: As an aside, stage 3 seems very odd to me. Why would you truncate your dimension table? Wouldn't his break referential integrity in any related fact tables? You would typically only upsert the dimension table using the staging table (how you would do this would depend on the type of dimension you have).